# Server.Mappath returning address without \

Tags: asp.net

```
Server.MapPath("/Uploads/CrystalReport1.rpt")
```

and

```
Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/CrystalReport1.rpt")
```

returning address without '\'

> D:WEBDATAmydomain.comUploadsCrystalReport1.rpt

but I expected

> D:\WEBDATA\mydomain.com\Uploads\CrystalReport1.rpt

Comment: Are you able to get the file?

Comment: I don't believe you.  Do a Trace.WriteLine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/CrystalReport1.rpt"));

Comment: Dim reportpath As String = Server.MapPath("/Uploads/CrystalReport1.rpt")
    Dim reportpath2 As String = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/CrystalReport1.rpt")
Then I am printing it with javascript

 Response.Write("<script>alert('1 " & reportpath & "');</script>")
            Response.Write("<script>alert('2 " & reportpath & "');</script>")
messagebox showing address without backslash

Comment: That is because javascript interpets the string, the value in reportpath is correct. No reason to send it to the client anyway, he can not access the path on the server. You should use de normal debuging tools for .net.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue, noted in the comments, is that javascript interprets "\" as a marker for special characters.  To output a backslash, you need to use two backslashes, as in "\".  For some reason, the output is different.  Instead of writing them out from the client, do a Response.Write from the code-behind, and examine the differences there, or even more simply, use VS intellisense to check.